# How to skip tap event on Unity UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a panel that can be scrolled (by a Drag event) but skips a tap event (like click event). When it receives a tap event it will skip to the next UI (behind the panel) which will then receive said tap event.

Is this possible to implement?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scroll View, it is more convenient to solve this task.
Here is Unity Lesson how to use it: https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/scroll-view